# Java Security Apache Shiro vs Picketlink

Tags: java, security, shiro, picketlink

I've got an Java EE application running with Apache Shiro to secure and authenticate to the website.

However I want to implement Single Sign on with Picketlink.

Is it possible to implement it "on top" or do I have to disable Shiro and do the whole authentication with Picketlink?

On the web I couldn't find any reference.